# How can I find increasing id number in listview after click delete button

Tags: android

I have a **ListView** which has three **TextView** in each row (**id**, **product_name**, **product_price**)

I am displaying **product_name** and **product_price** from database and show the id as increasing (1, 2, 3, 4) by increase arrayList.size() + 1.

Delete button in every row.

When user clicks to delete button as (id - 3) to delete row, I cannot find Id to show increasing number (1, 2, 3).

Now my list view show (1, 2, 4). How can I do it?

QuickKeysAdapter

```
public class QuickKeysAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Context mContext;
private List<sellProductInfo> dataQuickKeys;
private List<String> imageQuickKeys;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<sellOrderDetailInfo> _listsellOrderDetailInfo;
private sellProductLogic _sellProductLogic;

public String flagDelete = "";

public QuickKeysAdapter(Context paramContext,
        List<sellProductInfo> paramList1, List<String> paramList2) {
    this.mContext = paramContext;
    this.dataQuickKeys = paramList1;
    this.imageQuickKeys = paramList2;

    Log.v("QKey", "Hay Chan! i in QuickKeysAdapter()");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (dataQuickKeys == null) ? 0 : dataQuickKeys.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return paramInt;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return paramInt;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    View gridView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        try {
            gridView = new View(mContext);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);

            ImageView albumImage = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            albumImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_f); // temporatory

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imgview = albumImage;
            viewHolder.txtname = txtTitle;
            viewHolder._linearLayout = (LinearLayout) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

            gridView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("view null", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        gridView = convertView;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) gridView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.txtname.setText(dataQuickKeys.get(position).getDescEng()
            .toString());

    viewHolder._linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickQuickKeys(
            this.dataQuickKeys.get(position)));

    return gridView;
}

class OnClickQuickKeys implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String btnname;
    private String product_code;

    public OnClickQuickKeys(sellProductInfo sellProductInfo) {
        this.btnname = sellProductInfo.getDescEng();
        this.product_code = sellProductInfo.getProductCode();
        Log.d("OnClick", "Chan! I'm Constructor");

        Log.d("OnClick1", "Chan2! " + btnname + " " + product_code);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.d("OnClick", product_code.toString());

        Toast.makeText(mContext, btnname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _sellProductLogic = new sellProductLogic(mContext);
        _listsellOrderDetailInfo = _sellProductLogic
                .getallsellProductDetailLogic(product_code);

        MainActivity._PrdSellListAdapter = new PrdSellListAdapter(mContext,
                MainActivity._listsellOrderDetailInfo);
        MainActivity.lvprdcurrentsell
                .setAdapter(MainActivity._PrdSellListAdapter);


        Log.v("CC", "Chan , onclick call me orderdetail = "
                + MainActivity._listsellOrderDetailInfo.size() + 1);

        int prdId = MainActivity._listsellOrderDetailInfo.size() + 1;
        String a = Integer.toString(prdId);

        MainActivity._sellOrderDetailInfo = new sellOrderDetailInfo();
        MainActivity._sellOrderDetailInfo
                .setPrdname(_listsellOrderDetailInfo.get(0).getPrdname()
                        .toString());
        MainActivity._sellOrderDetailInfo
                .setPrditemprice(_listsellOrderDetailInfo.get(0)
                        .getPrditemprice());

        MainActivity._sellOrderDetailInfo.setPrdId(prdId);

        //
        MainActivity._listsellOrderDetailInfo
                .add(MainActivity._sellOrderDetailInfo);

        Log.v("InClick", "Chan , onclick call me orderdetail = " + prdId);

        if (flagDelete == "U") {
            for (int i = 1; i <= MainActivity._listsellOrderDetailInfo
                    .size(); i++) {
                MainActivity._sellOrderDetailInfo.setPrdId(i);

            }
        }   

    }
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtname;
    ImageView imgview;
    LinearLayout _linearLayout;
}
} 
}
```

prdsellListadapter class

```
 public class PrdSellListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
private TableLayout tblLayout;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public static ListView lvprdcurrentsell;

private List<sellOrderDetailInfo> _sellOrderDetailInfo;
private sellProductLogic _sellProductLogic;

public PrdSellListAdapter(Context paramContext,
        List<sellOrderDetailInfo> paramList1) {

    // this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(paramContext);
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) paramContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    this._sellOrderDetailInfo = paramList1;
    this.mContext = paramContext;

    int prdId = MainActivity._listsellOrderDetailInfo.size();
    Log.v("PSlA", "Hay Chan ! Don't Worry , i constructor ");
}

public PrdSellListAdapter(List<sellOrderDetailInfo> _sellOrderDetailInfo) {
    this._sellOrderDetailInfo = _sellOrderDetailInfo;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {     

    if (_sellOrderDetailInfo.size() <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return _sellOrderDetailInfo.size();
    }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
    final ViewHolder localViewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {      

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentsellprdlist, null);
        localViewHolder = new ViewHolder();         

        localViewHolder.txtPrdId = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdId);
        localViewHolder.txtPrdName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdName);
        localViewHolder.txtPrdQty = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdQty);
        localViewHolder.txtPrdPrice = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdPrice);
        localViewHolder.txtPrdTotal = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdTotal);
        localViewHolder.buttonprddeletecs = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        convertView.setTag(localViewHolder);
    } else {
        localViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        Log.v("PSlA", "Hay Chan ! I'm not null convertView ");
    }

    // set value into localviewhloder'variable      

    if (_sellOrderDetailInfo.size() <= 0) {

    } else {        

        localViewHolder.txtPrdId.setText(Integer
                .toString(_sellOrderDetailInfo.get(position).getPrdId()));
        localViewHolder.txtPrdName.setText(_sellOrderDetailInfo
                .get(position).getPrdname().toString());
        localViewHolder.txtPrdPrice.setText(_sellOrderDetailInfo
                .get(position).getPrditemprice().toString());

        Log.v("PSlA",
                "Hay Chan ! I'm get view :) " + _sellOrderDetailInfo.size());

        localViewHolder.buttonprddeletecs
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                view.getContext());

                        alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");

                        alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {
                                        // I get from the bundle the Id of
                                        // my employee
                                        PrdSellListAdapter.this._sellOrderDetailInfo
                                                .remove(position);
                                        // 
                                        PrdSellListAdapter.this
                                                .notifyDataSetChanged(); 

                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                mContext,
                                                "Delete button Clicked : "
                                                        + position,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                        alertDialog.show();

                    }
                });

    }
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    Button buttonprddeletecs;
    TextView txtPrdId;
    TextView txtPrdName;
    TextView txtPrdQty;
    TextView txtPrdPrice;
    TextView txtPrdTotal;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want in the ID in 1,2,3 order, why don't use the position in `getView` function to show the ID?

Answer (score 0):

Now , I update my some code getview method in prdsellListadapter class. It work for me to get serial id after click delete .

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.v("PSlA", "Hay Chan ! Don't Worry .I'm " + position);

    // final ViewHolder localViewHolder;

    final ViewHolder localViewHolder;
    View gView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        Log.v("PSlA", "Hay Chan ! I'm null convertView ");

        gView = new View(mContext);
        gView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentsellprdlist, null);

        localViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        Log.v("PSlA", "Hay Chan ! I'm null convertView 1");

        localViewHolder.txtPrdId = (TextView) gView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdId);
        localViewHolder.txtPrdName = (TextView) gView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdName);
        localViewHolder.txtPrdQty = (TextView) gView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdQty);
        localViewHolder.txtPrdPrice = (TextView) gView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdPrice);
        // localViewHolder.txtPrdTotal = (TextView) gView
        // .findViewById(R.id.txtPrdTotal);
        localViewHolder.buttonprddeletecs = (Button) gView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        localViewHolder._linearLayout = (LinearLayout) gView
                .findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

        gView.setTag(localViewHolder);

    } else {
        gView = convertView;
        localViewHolder = (ViewHolder) gView.getTag();
        Log.v("PSlA", "Hay Chan ! I'm not null convertView ");
    }

    if (_sellOrderDetailInfo.size() <= 0) {
        Log.v("P", "chanchan i have no data");
    } else {

        try {
            localViewHolder.txtPrdId
                    .setText(Integer.toString(_sellOrderDetailInfo.get(
                            position).getPrdId()));
            localViewHolder.txtPrdName.setText(_sellOrderDetailInfo
                    .get(position).getPrdname().toString());
            localViewHolder.txtPrdPrice.setText(_sellOrderDetailInfo
                    .get(position).getPrditemprice().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.v("PSlA",
                "Hay Chan ! I'm get view :) " + _sellOrderDetailInfo.size());

        localViewHolder.buttonprddeletecs
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View view) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                view.getContext());

                        alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");

                        alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {

                                        PrdSellListAdapter.this._sellOrderDetailInfo
                                                .remove(position);

                                        localViewHolder.txtPrdName
                                                .setText("chanlay");

                                        int a = PrdSellListAdapter.this._sellOrderDetailInfo
                                                .size();

                                        PrdSellListAdapter.this
                                                .notifyDataSetChanged(); // refresh_method

                                        String aa = "";

                                        for (int i = 1; i <= PrdSellListAdapter.this._sellOrderDetailInfo
                                                .size(); i++) {
                                            aa = localViewHolder.txtPrdName
                                                    .getText().toString();
                                        }
                                        PrdSellListAdapter.this
                                                .notifyDataSetChanged(); // refresh_method

                                        Log.v("pp",
                                                localViewHolder.txtPrdName
                                                        .getText()
                                                        .toString());

                                        ButtonFlag = "D";
                                    }
                                });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                        alertDialog.show();

                    }
                });

        if (ButtonFlag == "D") {
            for (int i = 1; i <= PrdSellListAdapter.this._sellOrderDetailInfo
                    .size(); i++) {
                // localViewHolder.txtPrdId.setText(String.valueOf(i));

                localViewHolder.txtPrdId.setText(String
                        .valueOf(position + 1));

            }
        }
        Log.v("cp", localViewHolder.txtPrdName.getText().toString());
    }
    return gView;
}
```